# Error: More than one instance of library found

Tags: webpack, karma-mocha

I'm importing `bitcore-mnemonic` in my React project with this conditions:

- I'm importing it just once and in one file.
- The component utilising it is imported just once and is called by `react-router`.
- No other library is using `bitcore-lib`. How did I find? searched `node_modules`.
- I'm importing as `import mnemonic from 'bitcore-mnemonic';`.

And I'm getting this error while running unit tests:

> Uncaught Error: More than one instance of bitcore-lib found. Please make 
>   sure to require bitcore-lib and check that submodules do not also
>   include their own bitcore-lib dependency.

Please help me know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bitcore-lib` creates a global object named `_bitcore`, and every time you want to create an instance it checks to make sure that object is not available.
To solve this, I simply delete this variable before requiring:

```
if (global._bitcore) delete global._bitcore;
const mnemonic = require('bitcore-mnemonic');
```

- Remember you can not use `import` instead of `require`(Hoisting).
- If you're using `webpack`, it takes care of multiple `import`/`require` statements.